# How to remove nested object by Id from Formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am trying to remove an entire flight item from a nested array. I've tried setFieldvalue. Whenever I find a specific ID, i'd like to remove the entire item from Formik. For some reason the internet is sparse with solutions, even on SO.

```
console.log("Formik", formik.values.flightsById);
    for (let item in formik.values.flightsById){
      if(item === 'EF_700001132'){
        console.log("it's here: ", item)
        // React.useEffect(() => () => formik.setFieldValue(item, undefined), [])
        //formik.values.flightsById.remove

      }
    }
    console.log("Formik after del: ", formik.values.flightsById);
```

Console.log() results:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some feedback:

- You referred to `flightsById` as a "nested array", but judging from your screenshot it's an object
- You have the right idea by using `setFieldValue()` to update `flightsById`, nice work
- Placing a useEffect inside an `if` statement will trigger an error because it breaks the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)
- If you want to completely remove they key `EF_700001132` from the `flightsById`, you will need to clone `flightsById` except for that key, and then pass it into `setFieldValue()`. I used the [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) (`...otherFlights`) to copy it without the key, but there's plenty of other methods detailed in other SO threads.

Here is an example of deleting a single flight when a button is clicked:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => {
    const { EF_700001132, ...otherFlights } = formik.values.flightsById;
    formik.setFieldValue("flightsById", otherFlights);
  }}
>
  Delete Flight EF_700001132
</button>
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-t2dmy?file=/index.js:1106-1139)

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up doing this "formik.setFieldValue(flightId, undefined);" and it deleted the entire object.